# Improve Disk Performance of a Linux 2.4 Guest on KVM Host

Tags: linux, performance, kvm-virtualization

I have a server running Linux 2.4, and I'd like to virtualize it using KVM.
I can run it with a IDE controller, but my applications require more disk performance.

The best existing solution is using VirtIO paravirtualization, but there's no driver for Linux 2.4, and I can't upgrade it to 2.6 or 3.x due to my applications' constraints.
I tried using the SCSI controller, but the server doesn't boot because SeaBios doesn't support boot from a SCSI disk.

Is there any alterantive with better performance than IDE controller that works under Linux 2.4 guest?

Comment: How can an application be constrained to the 2.4 kernel?! What is it?

Comment: If the machine will run in a virtualized environment, it will presumably be using a virtual disk. If IDE is a bottleneck there, I fear it will be with SCSI or whatever else you throw at it.

Comment: Which distribution of Linux is your 2.4 guest?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The application is tied to the distro, which is based on 2.4 kernel. We cannot change the kernel without changing the distro.

Comment: Again, what is it?

Comment: @HTTP500 It's Mandrake 8.2.

Comment: @MichaelHampton A set of proprietary software.

Comment: Is it too late to shoot the developers? I'm having trouble coming up with much of anything that really needs to be tied to a specific kernel version. It's quite possible that it isn't actually so, or can be trivially fixed.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The developers said the software depends strongly on services, specific compiler version and libs of this distro, and it's not trivial fixing it :( It depends on the distro, and changing its kernel to 2.6.x is too difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Red Hat backported the virtio drivers to 2.4 to help companies P2V their ancient RHEL3 systems: http://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHEA-2010-0157.html

Comment: I'm using another distro, but I'll try it.

Comment: That will be problematic. You'll need to use the RHEL kernel as well.

Comment: It worked on Mandrake 8.2! Thanks!

I haven't tried the VirtIO network driver yet, but the disk driver is OK, after some modifications.

Comment: After some more modifications, VirtIO network driver is working as well =D